# github: discard my own fork, start over with fork from original, preserving my local changes

Tags: git, github

This is the situation:

Someone else has the "main" project on github, which I forked (on github) long ago, then made changes, eventually ending up with with my own mess which I do not want to keep any more.

Now, I pulled the main's latest version to my local repository and make a few changes. I like to share this new version on my github fork now.

This means there are 3 versions now:
1. Main original on github (to which I can't push).
2. My fork on github which I want to discard.
3. My local version which I like to get into my github repo.

What do I have to do to push my local version up to github, simply replacing everything that was there? Do I have to erase the repo on gitgub for that? Or is there a way to say: push this, replacing everything you have there already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you've added your github fork as a repo named `origin` and that you care about the master branch:

```
git push -f origin master:master
```

Repeat for each branch you want to replace.

If you have any branches on your old fork you want to delete,

```
git push origin :branch_name
```

Comment: I've tried the first suggestion already - when I try to push to my fork, it instead wants to push to the main one from which I pulled. Understand what I mean?

Comment: That means the remote is wrong; use `git remote add myfork git@github.com/myusername/repo` and then push to `myfork` instead.

Comment: I had both remotes already added: The one from which I pulled (the main one) and mine on github. So I specifiy to force-push to mine, and that asks me for the login credentials of the other one (which I don't have). -- Oh! With the cmdline it now seems to work. Guess I have to report a bug for SmartGit now...  Thanks!